# How can I make a list from a list of tuples ?

Tags: python, list, tuples

if I have a list of tuple like:

```
L=[(('a','b','c','d'),2),(('f','e','d','a'),3)]
```

I want to make a list that like:

```
L1=[['a','b','c','d'],['f','e','d','a']]
```

this is what I did:

```
L1=[]

for item in L:
    for(letter,integer) in item:
        L1.append(list(letter))
        print(L1)
```

but it comes up with error say that there are too many values to unpack

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: It shouldn't be a `for` loop; you just need `letter, integer = item`, I think.

Comment: The elements in `item` are a list of characters and a number. You are trying to assign a 4-element list (the characters) to two variables...

Answer (score 9):

What's useful here is a list comprehension:

```
L1 = [list(letters) for (letters, number) in L]
```

This iterates over each pair in your list, taking the letters tuple of each pair and converting it to a list. It then stores each result as the element of a new list.

Answer (score 2):

You did:

```
 for item in L:
      for(letter,integer) in item:
          L1.append(list(letter))
          print(L1)
```

However, `item` is already a tuple and there's no need to iterate through it. What you want is

```
for letter, integer in L:
    L1.append(list(letter))
```

Or...

```
for item in L:
    letter, integer = item
    L1.append(list(letter))
```

Answer (score 2):

you may try:

```
L1 = [list(i[0]) for i in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
for(letter,integer) in item:
```

This will (try to) iterate over `item`, which is a 2-element tuple. Replace it by:

```
(letter,integer) = item
```

And it will work. There are more concise ways of doing that, of course, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do that, one of them is to map your list by getting first element, eg. like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(list, map(itemgetter(0), L))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['f', 'e', 'd', 'a']]
```

The other one is to use list comprehensions:

```
>>> [list(item[0]) for item in L]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['f', 'e', 'd', 'a']]
```

or lambda:

```
>>> map(lambda x: list(x[0]), L)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['f', 'e', 'd', 'a']]
```

But maybe you do not need a list and tuple will do. In such case the examples are simpler:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(0), L)
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('f', 'e', 'd', 'a')]
>>> [item[0] for item in L]
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('f', 'e', 'd', 'a')]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], L)
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('f', 'e', 'd', 'a')]
```

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @JBernardo: Your quote (basically the only content from your comment, in addition to quote characters) is well-known quote from Zen of Python (PEP20, as far as I remember), but it gives no feedback on my answer. Basically there **are** multiple ways to do it and different people prefer `map()`, others prefer comprehension. In this case it all depends on OP's code, which we do not know in full, so I leave this to OP to decide which one is better (I prefer `map()`, when using previously existing functions only, and comprehensions when I would have to use `lambda`).

Comment: @JBernardo: About the choice: I think this simple case is just narrowed version of the problem OP is facing, so I have given multiple options. When it comes to the last part (using `tuple`s anyway), it is expansion of basic answer in the case, when OP actually does not need to convert every `tuple` to `list` - and this is very often the case when it will be just iterated, not passed further for modification (like appending new values). Anyway, it is up to OP to choose better option.

Comment: Everytime someone uses `map`, Guido Van Rossum cries

Comment: @julio.alegria: ;) I disagree, he created map(), he left it in Python 3.x (as opposed to reduce()), and it is often very useful (shortens the code, makes it clearer). I consider map(sth, L) to be a lot clearer than [sth(i) for i in L] or, in Python 3.x rather (but not exactly): (sth(i) for i in L). map() has its place (as does eg. operator.itemgetter).

Comment: I think map is great, and has its uses. However, I am against explicit numeric indexing of lists. The reason is because python is duck-typed. There is nothing to give any clue as to what is stored in `item[0]`. I think tuple unpacking is glorious, and serves as a reminder as to what the contents of tuple consist of. This is why I prefer list comprehensions to map in most circumstances as you lose sight of what data you're operating on.